# conda activate /data/jupyter/myenv fails in jupyterhub notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, conda, jupyterhub

I created a new conda environment in a specific path using -p:
`$ conda create -p /data/jupyter/myenv`

Now if I run in a **Jupyterhub** notebook:
`!source activate /data/jupyter/myenv`

There are no errors in the Notebook output.

But then check the environments in the Notebook:
`!conda env list`

I get:

```
# conda environments:
#
                         /data/jupyter/myenv
base                  *  /data/opt/anaconda3
```

I am unable to activate the myenv inside the Jupyter notebook. But if I run the same command inside a bash terminal then I can activate the new environment. I also did `!conda init bash` and tried `!source activate` and `!conda activate` in the Notebook with same results. How can I activate the new environment inside the Jupyterhub Notebook cell. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This got resolved by running:
`$ conda install  nb_conda_kernels`
in both the (base) environment and the (/data/jupyter/myenv) environment.

After that refresh the Jupyter notebook browser and you will see the new active environments:

```
!conda env list
# conda environments:
#
                      *  /data/jupyter/myenv
base                     /data/opt/anaconda3
```